# When attempting to select an Outlook rule to run, no rules appear

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I'm trying to select a rule to run in Outlook 2013.  From the ribbon, I select "Rules", then click the "Run Rules Now..." button under the "E-mail Rules" tab and no rules appear to be run.  To be clear, *many* rules have been created and exist, but none appear when I attempt to run them individually.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Appreciative for the help.

Matt

Comment: Have you upgraded Outlook since creating these rules?

Comment: No, haven't upgraded my Outlook client.  I've had the same installation for about 4 years. I did perform a repair on the Office 2013 install from Control Panel -> Programs and Features to see if that would fix the situation - no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were these rules all created on a outlook client? And could these rules run normally in your outlook?

As I know, if we created outlook rules on other client and choose "on this computer only" condition, the rules would be declared "For other computer" and we couldn't run it in new client.
[image]

If that's your case, we could try to edit the rule and uncheck "on this computer only" option to solve it.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!